# Column vanished overnight

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

A column in a SharePoint list vanished overnight and I can't find it anywhere. This happened twice already in the same list. I noticed it when trying to adjust a Workflow and a step suddenly showed "Field" instead of the fields name. The Field is also no longer "selectable" in the form (the field's name is still there but the dropdown where you should choose the field's value isnt there). How can this happen? Or how can I prevent this? It happened last night and the night before with the exact same field (I recreated the field yesterday).

Comment: Install [the SharePoint Inspector Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sharepoint-insider/gjckpigahcbffmeofjfedlffddhfidhj) OR the [SharePoint Client Browser](https://spcb.codeplex.com/) and check the Lists properties for the last modified info. This smells like something else (created by a human) is running and messing with your List.

Comment: The time shown there is probably in the server's time, right? It looks like it has been modified (according to the LastItemModifiedDate property) today around 7:30 AM my time (CET), but that cant have been me. But anyway I dont think anyone (except my boss) with the sufficient rights knows of this list, since it's still WIP. And I dont think there's any reason to delete that column aswell.

Comment: You now have proof *something* not you touched your list. Next quest is to find out what proces did that, then who initiated that proces. 7:30 and not 29 or 31 smells like a scheduled task

Comment: Well it wasnt exactly 7:30 I was just rounding up... I recreated the column and look if it's still there on Monday. It's just that this happened from Wednesday to Thursday aswell... I will see...

Comment: Go to your admins and ask "Are there any wake-up or other scripts being run around 7:30??" SharePoint does not do freaky things like this by itself